# HTTP error 422 in authentication response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a ruby on rails app running in a machine with nginx web-server. For authentication we are using Keycloak. When user try to authenticate, request goes to keycloak. On redirecting after authentication from keycloak server, when nginx accepting connection, it shows error HTTP/2.0" 422 0 in logs. Also http 422 is displayed in browser.

I have tried adding below header, which did not work. Also tried with some location / and proxy /
`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'`

I tried running the app without nginx(using puma) and it did work.
Below is my conf file for nginx

````
 default upgrade;
 ''      close;
}
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name example.com;
 root /home/live/public;
 # Useful for Let's Encrypt
 location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { allow all; }
 location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
}
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
 server_name example.com;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!NULL:!SHA;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
 ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem;
 keepalive_timeout    70;
 sendfile             on;
 client_max_body_size 80m;
 root /home/live/public;
 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";
 gzip_vary on;
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_comp_level 6;
 gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
 location / {
   try_files $uri @proxy;
 }
 location ~ ^/(emoji|packs|system/accounts/avatars|system/media_attachments/files) {
   add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
   try_files $uri @proxy;
 }
 location /sw.js {
   add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0";
   try_files $uri @proxy;
 }
 location @proxy {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   proxy_set_header Proxy "";
   proxy_pass_header Server;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   tcp_nodelay on;
 }
 location /api/v1/streaming {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   proxy_set_header Proxy "";
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
   tcp_nodelay on;
 }
 error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;
} ```

I need nginx to pass the data getting form keycloak, back to my ruby on rails application.
````

Comment: Have you followed the config steps here? https://github.com/looorent/keycloak-api-rails

Comment: Yes @Mark . This authentication works fine on running without nginx. I tried running in puma and it did work.

Comment: You might have tried already but https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/08/configuring-nginx-keycloak-oauth-oidc/ looks like your same issue

Comment: Thanks @Mark . We had a look but have not tired. I will post the results. Thanks again.